# Finding the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2-e^{3i\theta}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

To find the real and imaginary parts of $$\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2-e^{3i\theta}}.$$ I multiplied the expression by the conjugate of the denominator to get $$\frac{2e^{i\theta}+e^{4i\theta}}{4-e^{-\theta^2}}.$$

This then simplified to give $$\frac{(2\cos(3\theta)+\cos(4\theta))+i(2\sin(3\theta)+\sin(4\theta))}{4-e^{-\theta^2}}$$

from which I could easily get the real and imaginary parts

$$\text{Re}=\frac{(2\cos(3\theta)+\cos(4\theta))}{4-e^{-\theta^2}} ,\ \text{Im}=\frac{i(2\sin(3\theta)+\sin(4\theta))}{4-e^{-\theta^2}}.$$

However obviously these aren't very nice expressions so I'm wondering if there is any way I can get simpler real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I think you missed a $3\times3$ when you multiplied by $(2+e^{3i\theta})$ in the first line

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't think there's nicer expressions for the real and imaginary parts (I think they're probably as simple as they can get): WolframAlpha can't come up with anything either http://bit.ly/2i9Pa9X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was using the wrong conjugate and incorrect simplification
$$(2-e^{3i\theta})(2+e^{3i\theta}) = 4 - (e^{3i\theta})^2 = 4-e^{6i\theta}$$

**Hint:** Use the *complex* conjugate
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2-e^{3i\theta}}\cdot\frac{2-e^{-3i\theta}}{2-e^{-3i\theta}}$$

Doing this simplifies the denominator
$$(2-e^{3i\theta})(2-e^{-3i\theta}) = 5 - 2(e^{3i\theta}+e^{-3i\theta}) = 5-4\cos(3\theta) $$

You can do the rest

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2-e^{3i\theta}}=\frac{e^{i\theta}\color{red}{(2-e^{-3i\theta})}}{(2-e^{3i\theta})\color{red}{(2-e^{-3i\theta})}}=\frac{2e^{i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}{|2-e^{3i\theta}|^2}$$

$$=\frac{(2\cos\theta-\cos(-2\theta)+i(2\sin\theta+\sin(-2\theta)))}{|2-e^{3i\theta}|^2}$$

Can you finish?